# ld.exe: cannot find -ld3d12 - Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, mingw-w64

My CMakeLists looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Example VERSION 0.1)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)


find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "C:/opencv/build/x64/mingw64/")
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Multimedia Gui)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS OpenGL REQUIRED)
#find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Gui REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${Qt6_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(main ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Qt6_LIBS} Qt6::Gui Qt6::OpenGL)
```

But whenever I add find Qt in my CMakeLists I get the following error related to Direct X 12:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ld3d12
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I couldn't find anything related to my issue.

I'm on VScode windows 10 using Qt6 installed using online installer. The code works fine using Qt creator but without using CMakeLists.